# Upload page after navigating back

Tags: html, iframe, browser-cache

`Hi, everybody.`

I have a web page that contains link to another resource and a frame which updates every second (by another program). When I follow the link and then back (with browsers's back button), frame stops being updated.
I have tried to add `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />`
to both files but it hasn't work. Here are my code files:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="https://www.google.com"> Link </a>
        <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
<div style="background-color: #250A69; color:#F0F0F0">
   Hello, I'm frame
</div>
```

I need solution with HTML, but can't find it anywhere, please help.

Comment: what happens if you hit the refresh button in you browser after navigating back from the link?

Comment: It makes frame to update again, but it is not clear for some users, so they will think that frame is still refreshing.

Comment: Sure, was just curious. What is actually in the iframe.html? I mean, the stub you posted does not change anything when it's refreshed.

Comment: Another program which outputs its report to html file does that.

Comment: dont' know the solution, just some hints: What if the link would be inside the iframe and you'd open this directly. I mean, try it without "iframe", to see where the problem comes from.